# visible column depend on model field in kendo mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
 public PartialViewResult grid(int Id, Choices? field)
            {
      var model =  new Model
                {
                   Id = Id,
                    Choice = choice.HasValue ? section : choice.First
                };
                return PartialView("_Grid",  model);
            }
```

Model

```
public class Model
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public Choices? Choice { get; set; }
}

public enum Choices
{
    First=1,
    Second,
}
```

In View data shows but column doesnt dissapear when I change Choice.

```
   @model Model
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Item>()
                  .Name("Grid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                               {
     columns.Bound(c => c.f).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight:bold;" }).Hidden(Model.Section != Choices.Second);
                               } )
```

Markup for choice

```
<select id="Choice" name="Choice">
    <option selected="selected" value="1"> First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

event for choice

```
$('#Choice').on('change', function () {
    var selectSection = $('#Choice').val();
    var orderId = $('#OrderId').val();
   $.post("@Url.Action("grid", "Project")"), { orderId: orderId, section: selectSection }, function (data) {
    });
}
```

How I can manage visible in column in kendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work only on initialize grid

```
.Hidden(Model.Section != Choices.Second)
```

You should use `dataBound Event`

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
```

and define function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function onDataBound(arg) {
    var grid = this.wrapper.data("kendoGrid");
    if(Model.Section != Choices.Second)
        grid.hideColumn("f");
    else
        grid.showColumn("f")
}
</script>
```

[Some kendo docs about dataBound event](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events)

hide column on `Choice` change

```
$('#Choice').on('change', function () {
    var grid=$('grid')..data("kendoGrid");
    var selectSection = $('#Choice').val();
    var orderId = $('#OrderId').val();
    if(selectSection = 1)  
        grid.hideColumn("f");
    else
        grid.showColumn("f")
}
```

Comment: Model and Choices are not defined in script

Comment: And dataBound event appear when page is loaded, but it doestnt run when i work with ddl

Comment: You should get Model and Choices by youself, i dont see clear where you store them.

Comment: Edit answer for hide column on Choices value change. DataBound event fire when you update datasource of grid.

Comment: Ok. but now hidecolumn/showcolumn isnt  defined. $('grid') = []

Comment: $('value') - is jquery selector for element with id=value. To make it worked add `.HtmlAttributes(new { id = "grid" })` to grid description

Comment: Ok. I understand. Can i use toggleColumn or only show/hide?

Comment: I think show/hide is only avaliable methods for hide column provided by kendo. But you can add `visibility: visible | hidden` html tag in `column.css('visibility: hidden')`